# Why did Avatar Roku destroy the temple after talking with Aang?

Tags: plot-explanation, avatar-the-last-airbender

I just finished watching the *Avatar: The Last Airbender* episode "Winter Solstice Part 2 - Avatar Roku". Towards the end of the episode once Aang is done talking with Roku he (Avatar Roku) proceeds to destroy the tower.

Why does Avatar Roku destroy the tower in the end?

The tower being destroyed:
[image: Tower]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He destroyed the temple because the sages had become corrupt, so he wanted to get rid of them and the firebenders. It was to protect Aang, and there was no more use in the temple after he had already talked to him.